# Break process without breakpoint in c++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-c++, mfc

In Visual Studio 2008 MFC application is there a way to stop the debugging without a breakpoint, when I press a button? The problem is, it's a pretty big and shared project, so my code is called by another "module", but I don't know which of my functions are called, so I don't know where to put a breakpoint. My goal would be to break the process, if any of my functions are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a Visual Studio macro that puts a breakpoint on every line in your source code. You could make it a bit smarter and only put breakpoints on each function start, but that would require some parsing. Bind that macro to a key. Run the MFC application and when you want to start breaking on your own code, switch to Visual Studio, press the key and presto, you will break on the first use of your code.

The other option is to make a C++ macro that checks if a global boolean has been set and executes asm { int 3 } when it has. Use this macro at the start of every (high level) function of your code. Add code that sets the global boolean when a certain button is pressed in the MFC application. This will only work in a 32-bit executable, you'll need some intrinsic in a 64-bit executable, which I don't know by head.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Sebastiaan

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "Pause" button that breaks the execution... Or you can put a breakpoint on all the possible suspects. You don't know which of your functions is called - put a break on all of them. Then you'll achieve your goal.

> My goal would be to break the process, if any of my functions are called.

Comment: If I press pause, it says there is no sourcecode available for the current location, because I don't have the other modul's source. Putting a breakpoint in all of the functions(over 1000) manually it would be a pain in the ***.

Comment: Use debug conditions. Compile in some code in each of your functions that will call some single piece of code, or drop a macro there or something that you can compile in for debug and compile out for release. You do it once, and yes - it's a pain. But once you've done it - you can easily debug your code every time you need.